# Event driven Progress Bar - Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to implement an event driven process bar in my website. Where can I find one? Which ones would you recommend?

An event driven progress bar is similar to a loading bar, but instead of a percentage it progresses when progresses are completed. So I have a workflow that does 8 tasks. When task 1 is finished the progress back progresses 1/8 and task 2 is begun.

Ideally it could also display the 8 tasks [name or maybe description] on the bar

Thanks

**Clarification**
I'm looked for these bars and have only found percentage progress bars. I don't know if there currently are event driven progress bars

**Current Version of Question**
Is there a progress bar that can display text on or near the bar? This text would need to change depending on the progress of the bar.

An example would be:

10% - The process is just beginning
20% - It's getting there
...

Comment: This site isn't for suggesting libraries.  Have you tried looking?  Would you consider making your own?

Comment: Yes I've looked and I haven't found anything. I'm asking because I think there probably is some version of an event driven progress bar, but it probably has a different name and I should be searching something else

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to take a percentage one and modify it yourself.  10 tasks, each task is 10%...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you find this site?

http://workshop.rs/2012/12/animated-progress-bar-in-4-lines-of-jquery/

They have this example:

http://workshop.rs/demo/progress-bar-in-4-lines/demo2.php

jQuery UI has this line of code you should check out:

```
if ( target.is( "#numButton" ) ) {
    progressbar.progressbar( "option", {
    value: Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 )
});

//you could easily change value: to be whatever number you need as each process finishes
```

From this page:

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#indeterminate

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, The example with the 4 pictures is ideal, because I can replace the pictures with the different tasks that are being done at each point in the process.